# Image not appearing in web server

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb

I am developing a social media site with a web server using mongo db. The issue is that when I try to  the image will not appear even if the right directory is used. Any ideas?

```
<div>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="guide.css">

    <h2>Volunteering and its Benefits</h2>

    <img src="http://localhost:3000/index.html#//volunteeraid/tabs/photos/info.jpg">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </p>

    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/DDZNm4KQE9o" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

    <h2>Preparing for and Handling Disasters</h2>


</div>
```

This is the code on a portion of a website

[image: Here is the result]

As you can see the image located in the top of the paragraph is not appearing

I used node server to access the site (localhost:3000)
Also this is the locaton for that module: http://localhost:3000/#//volunteeraid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<img src="http://localhost:3000/">
```

This should be pointing to your image. Not just the domain.

```
<img src="http://localhost:3000/image.jpg" />
```

Something like (you don't even need the domain name in front of it):

```
<img src="/image.jpg" />
```

**Edit**:

```
<img src="http://localhost:3000/index.html#//volunteeraid/tabs/photos/info.jpg">
```

Same thing, you won't get your image if pointing to a html file.

```
  <img src="/volunteeraid/tabs/photos/info.jpg">
```

You need to point directly to the image as stated above.

**Edit2**:

Make sure you can serve files:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.listen(8080);
```

Comment: yes but when i load just the div tag the photo appears, the problem starts when i used node and mongodb to access the site. There is no picture when i go to this module

Comment: @RagnaLugria see my edit. Not sure if that's your error, since you didn't specify anything about the setup. But that's the most common Node.js configuration (by using express package)

Comment: @RagnaLugria on your node.js main file. That should be your server loader

Answer (score 0):

Maybe add the name of an image?

```
<img src="http://localhost:3000/IMAGE.jpg">
```

or even better just the relative path

```
<img src="IMAGE.jpg">
```

**UPDATE**

After your update you posted the `src` with an image. It should probably look something like this

```
<img src="/photos/info.jpg">
```

Comment: both does not work, the directory for the photo is: <img src="photos/info.jpg">

Comment: @RagnaLugria just use this directory name then

Comment: yes it works but the picture above is the result when i use the web server

Comment: Where else would you use it?

Comment: my apologies i dont understand the question